# Mongodb timestamps for querying documents

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I want to fetch all the documents created on D-1 day, i.e. suppose if any record has been created on 4-12-2019 then query should fetch records created on 3-12-2019.

Here is my Model and code:

VENDOR ORDER SCHEMA

```
const vendorOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timesOfIndia:{
        tradeCopies:{
            type:Number,
            deafult:0 },
        subscriptionCopies:{
            type:Number,}
    },
    economicTimes:{
        tradeCopies:{
            type:Number,
            deafult:0
        },
        subscriptionCopies:{
            type:Number,}
    },
    mumbaiMirror:{
        tradeCopies:{
            type:Number,
            deafult:0
        },
        subscriptionCopies:{
            type:Number}
    },
    isApproved:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    vOrderCreator: 
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required:true
    }
},
{ timestamps: true }
)

const VendorOrder = mongoose.model('VendorOrder',vendorOrderSchema)
module.exports = VendorOrder
```

Query:

```
exports.getOrderById = async (req,res,next) =>{
    const vOrderCreator = req.params.id
    const vendorOrder = await VendorOrder.find({vOrderCreator,
                            createdAt: { $gt: new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) }   
                         }) 
    try {
        if (!vendorOrder) {
            const error = new Error('Could not find post.');
            error.statusCode = 404;
            throw error;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'VendorOrder fetched.', vendorOrder });
    } catch (err) {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }

        next(err);
    }}
```

POSTMAN RESPONSE

> {
>       "message": "VendorOrder fetched.",
>       "vendorOrder": [] // getting this empty array
>   }

Comment: always start investigation from data in database itself, please list some 2 documents you have with createdAt fields specified

Comment: Hi here are two doc created yesterday                                        
        
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-03T06:06:16.211Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-12-03T06:06:16.211Z")
        
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-03T06:10:19.728Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-12-03T06:10:19.728Z"),

Comment: try this in mongo client: db.collection.find({ createdAt: { $gt: ISODate('2019-12-03') } })

Comment: okay! Ivan that is working i am getting the documents in the shell now i am trying to make it dynamic in my orderController

Comment: Yup, what is working in shell 99.9999% should be working using mongo driver in given programming language

Comment: That is working in shell but not in node i am using {timestamps :true}

Comment: Hardly that timestmaps options has anything to do with this problem, as I understant it only helps to add createdAt, updatedAt on insert, while you trying to get items, which you know there. Try to simplify query and log out all items first, then add limitations.

Comment: Still getting to empty response, i have added createdDate:{type:Date,default:Date.now} in my schema and here is the saved document. 
    "createdDate": "2019-12-05T09:48:15.483Z",
    "createdAt": "2019-12-05T09:48:15.490Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-05T09:48:15.490Z"                                                   AND here is one of the query i tried---const vendorOrder = await 
       VendorOrder.find({
          "createdDate" : { "$gte" : Date((Date.now)-2),
           "$lt" : Date((Date.now)-1)}}) // in the nodejs